# Is it possible to tether my phone such that only traffic to one IP goes through it?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, routing, tethering

I am a contractor and I use all kinds of client equipment. I want to tether my phone so that I can remote to my home computer, however I don't want to use their corporate network to do so.

I've set up the tethering but all traffic then goes through my phone which locks me out of various intranet and IP restricted internal systems.

Is it possible to get windows to remote desktop using my tethered phone to my home computer, but all other traffic to be on the corporate network?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/959747/use-specific-network-adapter-for-specific-address

Comment: Hmm, I have tried setting my LAN to have priority, both in the adapter order and by setting its interface metric to a lower number, but traffic is still going over my phone. Perhaps there's a way to add a route to deny all traffic except that one IP?

Comment: In theory yes, add a 0.0.0.0/0 (aka default) route, or failing that a 0.0.0.0/1 plus 128.0.0.1/1, via the Ethernet gateway... But that's what the priority selection is supposed to do already, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sooooo tried quite a bit. Most things advise setting one network to have priority over the other, first, and then creating an override rule.

However this did not work for me, so I googled it and found that if you go into network connections and advanced to change the network order, this is ignored by windows (at least, windows 7), so it does nothing.

Next I read an article saying to change the interface metric, because windows will prioritise connections with the lower metric value. I set the lan to 1, the tether to 2. This also didn't work, and googling this said 'yup, windows tends to ignore this'.

So lastly I found an article that said the workaround is to disable all traffic to the adapter, and then add just the route you want.

This worked!

I ran this command:

`netsh interface ipv4 set interface [ID] ignoredefaultroutes=enabled`

I got my ID, which is just a number, from running:

`netsh interface ipv4 show interface`

Then, to set up the route, I set the metric of the connection to 2, in connection properties > tcpipv4 > advanced > uncheck automatic, and lastly I ran this:

`route add -p [mycomputersIP] [GatewayIPOfMyTetheringPhone] IF [ID as above] metric 2`

Be sure to use the gateway, not the IP.

And voila, it works!